# Compare two arrays with forEach and add different html elements on condition

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, foreach

I want to compare two arrays with forEach. When the two arrays have a matching element, it inserts an html element,
and, if there are no matching elements, it inserts a different html element.

```js
var array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    var array2 = [2, 4];
    
    array1.forEach(function(number1){
      array2.forEach(function(number2){
        if(number1 === number2){
          document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML += '<span>' + number1 + '</span>'
        } else {
          document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML += '<span class="inactive">' + number1 + '</span>'
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.inactive {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id='numbers'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the 2nd `Array.forEach()` call, you can use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if an item from the 1st array is found in the 2nd array:

```js
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const array2 = [2, 4];

array1.forEach(function(number1){
  console.log(array2.includes(number1) ? 'yes' : 'no');
});
```

Or in your case:

```js
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const array2 = [2, 4];

const numbers = document.getElementById('numbers');

array1.forEach(function(number1){
  const inactive = !array2.includes(number1) ? 'class="inactive"' : '';
  numbers.innerHTML += `<span ${inactive}> ${number1} </span>`;
});
```

```css
span:not(.inactive) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="numbers"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. But how would I do this if instead of numbers there were objects like "{number: '0', name: 'zero'}" and I wanted to check the number parameter

Comment: You would use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead, and if the result is `null`, you'll append the `inactive` class.

Comment: This will replace the includes line in the 2nd example - `const inactive = !array2.find(o => o.number === number1) ? 'class="inactive"' : ''`

Comment: Thanks that works, however you need to compare `o.number` with `number1.number`

Comment: Indeed. If both your arrays contain objects, you'll need to refer to the number property inside.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrayToHtml = array1.filter(el=>{
    el.includes(array2);
})
arrayToHtml.forEach(val=>{
    addHtml(tag,text);
})

function addHtml(tag, text){
    let newEl = document.body.creatElement(tag);
    newEl.textContent(text);
    document.body.appendChild(newEl)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested loops which is why you are getting 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4.

Step by step it goes:

1. number1 = 0
2. number2 = 2
3. if condition is wrong
4. output is 0 with inactive class
5. number1 = 0
6. number2 = 4
7. if condition is wrong
8. output is 0 with inactive class
9. number1 = 1
10. number2 = 2
11. if condition is wrong
12. output is 1 with inactive class
13. etc...

you should definitely consider defining a numbers variable so you only get that element once:

```
const numbers = document.getElementById('numbers');
```

using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would make your code more elegant:

```
array1.forEach(function(number1){
   if (array2.includes(number1)) {
       numbers.innerHTML += `<span> ${number1} </span>`;
   } else {
       numbers.innerHTML += `<span class="inactive"> ${number1} </span>`;
   }
});
```